# How do i update the UI with an update in the database

Tags: javascript, ajax, database, user-interface, web

I am trying to make a user registration type of page but i am displaying the details of all the registered users on the page dynamically.
Now suppose, I am trying to register using that page but some other user has already registered himself before me. How do i update this, to the UI, dynamically?

Is there any way to update the UI whenever a new entry is made in the database?

Comment: You can write a web service to access the database and retrieve relevant data periodically to display in the UI. You should consider the security aspects as well

Comment: But performance of such a service would be bad. isn't it?

Comment: you can have a column to indicate the created time of user and fetch users based on the timestamp. i.e: when retrieving users you can select only the newly added users without fetching all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval for call function after some interval. then it will display Latest entry from database.

```
setInterval(function() {
    your_function(); //call ajax function here
  },5000);
```

Hope it will help for you.